# In Ansible dynamic inventory, how do I filter host by a tag?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

**Stack:**

1. Git repository
2. Ansible AWX, Specifically, [AzureRM Inventory Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html)

**Problem:** I need to import the vm's in the inventory only if they have a certain tag and that that tag has a certain value to it.

**Context:**
Azure Inventory plugin has a filter, "exclude_host_filters", example provided in the documentation below:

```yaml
# excludes a host from the inventory when any of these expressions is true, can refer to any vars defined on the host
exclude_host_filters:
# excludes hosts in the eastus region
- location in ['eastus']
# excludes hosts that are powered off
- powerstate != 'running'
```

Problem: I am trying to use tags in the exclude host filters. Logically I need to:

1. Filter all the hosts that have a tag "owner" filtered.
2. Then filter in all the hosts that have tag "owner" with value "testing_ansible".

Here is what I tried to do:

```yaml
exclude_host_filters:
- if tags.owner is defined
- tags.owner != 'testing_ansible'
```

I also tried other filters but it didn't work. Documents requires jinja2 format.
How do I check if a tag exists and it has certain value to import the host?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the inventory plugin source code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/blob/dev/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py), filters defined in [exclude_host_filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html#parameter-exclude_host_filters) or [default_host_filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html#parameter-default_host_filters) are evaluated using this expression :

```
"{{% if filter %}} True {{% else %}} False {{% endif %}}"
```

The *if* in your first filter, doesn't permit this expression to be evaluated.
To check if a tag exists and it has certain value :

```
exclude_host_filters:
- tags.owner is defined
- tags.owner != 'testing_ansible'
```